# Changing values in a data frame with respect to corresponding data frame by setting a cutoff value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
D1 <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=1:5, z=1:5)
D2 <- data.frame(x=c(2,2,3,4,5),y= c(2,2,4,5,6),z= c(4,2,4,2,4))
```

The data in these two `data.frame`s comprise values from the same experiment. I would like to have the values for `x`, `y`, and `z` in `D1` to be set to 0, if values within D2 for any `x`, `y`, and `z` are less than 3.

The result that I am after is:

```
D1_output <- data.frame(x=c(0,0,3,4,5),y=c(0,0,3,4,5),z=c(1,0,3,0,5))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Would you like to change the values of D1 based on D2?

Answer (score 1):

```
D1 * (D2 >= 3)
  x y z
1 0 0 1
2 0 0 0
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 0
5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Neat @Onyambu. How did you decifer from the OP's question that this approach was needed? :) +1

Comment: @Dion because the expected output OP posted shows that we replace 0 with walues less than 3. any number  times 0 is 0 and any number  times 1 is the number.  So you just need a matrix with ones and zeros to multiply the original matrix and you will get the response. But how do we get the matrix of 1's and 0's? Just by doing the condition of >=3.